# can't retrieve POST parameters in controller

Tags: symfony, post

.Hi,
I try to get POST parameters in my symfony2 controller but `$request->request` returns `empty` if i send my params as POST, however if i send parameters as GET it works.

(I use Google Chrome REST Console for my tests).

Google Chrome REST Console Request body :

```
Request Url: http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/create-examination-report
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
Params: {
    "doctorId": "1",
    "examinationText": "On dirais bien que même en POST ca marche pas mal",
    "lat": "45.20354",
    "lng": "3.03265"
}
```

But in my controller if i use :

```
var_dump($request->request->all());
```

It result in `empty`, If i send the same request as GET it works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you print out the raw $_POST array ignoring the framework layer for a moment are the values there? (trying to establish if a symfony issue or something else going on...)

Comment: No it's not, it's still empty, do you thinks it's a bug with GC REST Console? Is there any other tool i can use? don't really want to write some CURL request ^^'

Comment: Either that or the post variables could be getting lost with some sort of redirect / rewriting of the URL perhaps?

Comment: For testing purposes I'd suggest going back to basics and just mock up a really simple web form with a couple of fields and post to the URL in question - if those values appear in your _POST output it would point towards something being up with GC REST Console...

Comment: Sounds like the GC REST Console have some bugs, or i misunderstand how it works, anyways with the same procedure i can have it working with 'Advanced Rest Client' GC extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Google `Chrome REST Console` have some problem to send POST request (for symfony at least..)

Using `Google Chrome Advanced Rest Client` solved my issue.